# Is there a Vue JS plugin similar to magicSuggest?

Tags: autocomplete, tags, vue.js, magicsuggest

I need a plugin to replicate the functionality I've been enjoying using [magicSuggest](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/examples.html).

I have found many autocomplete plugins for Vue but none that come bundled with tags.

Try any of the examples on this page to see how your selection is saved as a tag in the input.

http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/examples.html

I am after a plugin that will work with Vue js 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this gem, looks like a keeper. http://monterail.github.io/vue-multiselect/

Comment: Does not work with Vue 2.0 but they have a beta version that should work.

Comment: This one seems to be the best option, and it has a beta that works with Vue 2.0. Read the documentation if implementing for Vue 2.0 because a few of the option names have changed so you will need to update the examples before they will work in Vue 2.0

Answer (score 1):

You can also check dropdown provided by semantic-ui [here](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html), This can be easily integrated with VueJS.

Answer (score 0):

Also discovered this one, http://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/

Looks very similar to vue-multiselect.

Comment: You can use vue-select with Vue 2.0+. See Install in the readme:
https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select#install

Answer (score 0):

Try this [vue-multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/). Its supporting many options like tagging, search, multiple select, single select, asynchronous search, vuex and more.

https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect

`npm install vue-multiselect --save`

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0"></script>`
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css">`